# C# winapi.Closing child window in code

Tags: c#, winapi

I have created a child window to another application by winapi in C#. What is the proper way to close this window? When I send WM_CLOSE it closes all my application.

Answer (score 1):

Call `DestroyWindow` passing the child window handle.

You need to do this from the thread that created the window. If you aren't in control of that thread then sending `WM_CLOSE` to the child window handle will run `DestroyWindow` on the window's thread. Not sure why your current efforts failed since you didn't give much detail.